# What is the relationship between "srcset" and "sizes" attributes?

Tags: html, responsive-design, responsive, responsive-images, responsiveness

Suppose I'm using this `<img>` element below (the code has been taken from MDN):

```
<img srcset="elva-fairy-480w.jpg 480w,
             elva-fairy-800w.jpg 800w"
     sizes="(max-width: 600px) 480px,
            800px"
     src="elva-fairy-800w.jpg"
     alt="Elva dressed as a fairy">
```

As you can see, there are two options in the `srcset` attribute and two options for the `sizes` attribute. But can those be different? Can it be like 2 for `srcset` and 3 for `sizes` or the other way round?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`srcset` lists the available image files, while `sizes` defines the image's rendering dimensions at different breakpoints, so you can have very different numbers of items in each.

For example, you could have more available images (here we add one for large screens with a density of at least `2dppx`):

```html
<img srcset="elva-fairy-480w.jpg 480w,
             elva-fairy-800w.jpg 800w,
             elva-fairy-1600w.jpg 1600w"
     sizes="(max-width: 600px) 480px,
            800px"
     src="elva-fairy-800w.jpg"
     alt="Elva dressed as a fairy">
```

`sizes` depends on the various layouts the page have across the viewport widths, so you often have as many `sizes` item as different layouts.